# Uncaught Error: Error: An invalid exception was thrown

Tags: javascript, ajax, flash, externalinterface

I am trying to use ExternalInterface to call a Flash Function from javascript.

My JS:

```
function thisMovie(movieName) {
if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {
    return window[movieName]
}
else {
    return document[movieName]
}
}

function DoThis() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'POSTINGURLHERE',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { 'at': 1 },
    success: function(result) {
        thisMovie("ID").Lol(result['xD']);
    }
});
}
```

This code works perfectly on Localhost, just not on my public webhost?
I am getting on Google Dev Tools: http://prntscr.com/7mcxkb

I have the flash callbacks set in the swf, perfect for Localhost as mentioned.
So why is it not working on my webhost?

Comment: If you click in the errors in your dev tools console it will show you what line in your code threw it.  From the look of it, I would do two things: add a try... catch block in your thisMovie function and see if the error coming from there and add a failure callback in your ajax call.

Comment: Error: An Invalid Exception was thrown @Lukich

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this? I've been struggling with it for a week

Comment: Yes @Kesty I was trying to use the thisMovie function to an SWF which was on a subdomain.

Comment: @RobertMarley Thank you for responding! I was able to solve my issue in a few minutes due to you getting back about this.